# Lock all devices when adjusting pulseaudio volume in kmix

Tags: kde, audio, pulseaudio, volume

My problem is that kmix adjusts the volumes of not all devices locked together.
Adjusting built-in analog stereo also adjusts application's equalized stream and ALSA plugin. But webcam and event sounds are not locked and have to be adjusted separately. Also, when I strart an aplications, master can be at the middle, but the app volume is at maximum, so lowering it by hotkey lowers master from it's relative position.

For example "Built-In analog stereo" was at level 50% with "Unknown application"
Now I dolphin calls system sound on "delete". It plays very loud and when I open the kmix window - "Built-In analog stereo" now at 100% but other apps are where they were. By lowering "Built-In analog stereo" apps are getting lowered by the same amount (for example, ALSA plugin was 50% and is lowered with Built-In analog to 10% when analog was lwered from 100% to 60%).

I want kmix (or "built-in analog stereo" which is master right now) to to adjust one system-wide volume regardless whether are these pulseaudio devices or other.

[image: screenshot]